# Sitecore Powershell Extension - Trigger Index Refresh

Tags: sitecore

I was trying to trigger a index (the default sitecore_master_index) "refresh" on a context item (using SPE Context Menu). Here is the SPE script:

```
$item = Get-Item .

$index = [Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager]::GetIndex("sitecore_master_index")
[Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian]::Refresh($index, [Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreIndexableItem]$item)
```

However, I could not see there is a index update job appear in jobs.aspx and the index was not refreshed neither. Do you have any experience to achieve such job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Initialize-SearchIndex` command like that:

```
Get-SearchIndex -Name sitecore_master_index | Initialize-SearchIndex
```

Sitecore PSE documentation for this functionality:

> https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/initialize-searchindex

Comment: Thanks Marek, but what i was trying to do is not a rebuild. The default "sitecore_master_index" would contain a lot of docs and a full rebuild would take about 30mins in our current environment. That's why we want to try the "Refresh" which only update the docs under one specific item.